# Find User Id using the username of Linkedin developer API

Tags: linkedin-api

If I have a friends `Linkedin` User Name, how can I get his `UserId` using the Linked-In Developer APIs ?

For instance if my friends linkedin public URL is `https://www.linkedin.com/in/XXX-XXX-c802146` the username is `XXX-XXX-c802146`. So now I need to get the User Id of this user. How can I get this ?

Answer (score -1):

If you have the user's actual profile URL, just go to the page source and do a text search for `li:member:` and you should spot references to the actual profile ID.  This worked for my purposes.